# Drivers for MSI Z77MA-G45

Tags: drivers

I just purchased this motherboard (along with a core i5-3570 CPU).  The guy in the shop says it will work fine with Linux, and a search on the web shows that some people are indeed using it, but the MSI website only has drives for Windows.

Any idea where I might get the Linux drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just works.  Any drivers that were required must have been bundled in the Ubuntu install.  (I used v 12.04).